# Yii2: disable warning log message "Session is already started"

Tags: yii2

There are a lot of messages in my `'app.log'` file with content:

```
2018-03-28 12:23:55 [66.70.168.171][-][-][warning][yii\web\Session::init] Session is already started
```

**Question:** how to prevent this warning message from writing into log file?

I've tried to add `'except'` element in `'targets'`:

```
'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                'except' => [
                    'yii\web\Session', //here it is
                ],
            ],
```

But no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your exception does not use a wildcard, it will attempt to match an exact log category name

so you either add exception for an exact name (your case `yii\web\Session::init`)
or add a wildcard at the end `yii\web\Session:*` to filter all Session messages

```
'targets' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
        'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
        'except' => [
            'yii\web\Session:*', // Excludes all session messages
            // or
            'yii\web\Session::init', // Exclude only session init
        ],
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

yours_project -> vendor -> yiisoft -> yii2 -> web -> Session.php

comment out line 107, like this

```
if ($this->getIsActive()) {
   //Yii::warning('Session is already started', __METHOD__);
     $this->updateFlashCounters();
 }
```